# Single page app in sub directory, working html entry point but 404 on assets (css, js, ...)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im my Apache root directory a have 2 things, a .htaccess and a directory named app. Inside that directory there is a single page app. In the .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /app/ [L]
```

If I go to mysite.com, I can see the index document working, but all the assets called by index.html are missing:

[image]

And in fact if I try to query them directly from the browser they all go in 404, like mysite.com/vendor.js. What am I missing?

Comment: Where is `vendor.js` located?

Comment: @anubhava inside /app

Comment: ok and how are you invoking `css/js`? Are you using it like `/vendor.js` or just `vendor.js` ?

Comment: @anubhava the second one, vendor.js (with no slash)

Comment: Try this rule then: `RewriteRule !^app/ app%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]`

Comment: @anubhava thanks it works!

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this rule to forward all request to `app/` folder:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^app/ app%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```